# i need help, my 3D model looks broken

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

[image]

idk what happened, i just finished modeling the this and after i exit the edit mode this just happened, i reloaded the file and the same thing keep happening. i need help please thankyou..

Comment: Hello :). Don't you just have two identical models on top of each other? Because it seems like z-fighting.